# Multiple rows in mysql fetch

Tags: php

I have a select php script and the portion of it is:

```
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {         
  echo "<option>" . $row['firstname'] . $row['lastname'] . "</option>
  }                 
echo "</select>";                       
echo "</div>";
```

the problem are the rows, I am wanting them to appear in the option as "John Doe" the way it is now is "JohnDoe"

I have tried changing it to: . `$row['firstname'] . "&nbsp;" . $row['lastname'] .` but that would cause problems later on in the program where it wouldn't read the name as John Doe it would read it as John  Doe for some reason. (extra space)

Comment: echo "<option>" . $row['firstname'] .' '. $row['lastname'] . "</option>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can output a literal space:

```
echo "<option>" . $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'] . "</option>"
```

Also keep in mind, you can set the `value=""` attribute for `<option>` allowing you to display any output:

```
echo "<option value=\" . $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'] . \">Something Different</option>"
```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with `$row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname']...`? (It's a rhetorical question. That's how you should do it).

Answer (score 1):

If there is a possibility that the firstname fields can be empty you may want to do some trims to make sure you don't insert a leading space on the last name.

```
   echo "<option>" . trim(trim($row['firstname']) .' '. $row['lastname']) . "</option>";
```

Comment: why use trim twice in this way?

Comment: It will trim the spaces from firstname to correct for any trailing spaces there then remove any leading or tailing spaces from the combined string.

Comment: wouldn't that leave out all spaces in front of the `$row['lastname']`? i just thought you meant to do it like this `trim($row['firstname']) .' '. trim($row['lastname'])`

Comment: that would, if first name, was empty leave you with ` lastname`... It gets rid of the delimiting space in the case where you are missing either the first name or the last name so you aren't left with a leading or trailing space.

Comment: and that would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<option>" . $row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname'] . "</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<option>$row[firstname] $row[lastname]</option>";
```

Should work just fine for you. (Mind the placement of the quotes.)

Also, maybe, for later identification, you should add a 'value' tag to your option?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `$row['lastname']` is directly appended to `$row['firstname']`. To fix that, just put a space in between:

`echo "<option>".$row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname']."</option>";`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to fix it later in the program and echo a space like you want firstly.

Search for double spaces in the string and replace them with one space :

```
$str ='John  Doe'
$str = str_replace("  ", " ", $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, in your MySql query you could do something like this.

```
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT(`firstname`, ' ', `lastname`) AS `fullname` FROM `TABLENAME`";
```

and your PHP loop would look like this

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {         
     echo "<option>" . trim($row['fullname']) . "</option>"; //just incase, we trim it
 }
```

Comment: He is using `mysqli_`. Look closer.

Comment: since your going for mysql, it has a trim function too, other than that good answer